# How to identify the JAVACC parser unsuccessful programatically?

Tags: parsing, javacc

In javacc, how to check weather the input file is successfully passed the grammar or not? As an example, say I want to print "Filed parsed successfully" if the whole file is successfully parsed by the parser, and if not I want to print "File parsing faild!"

I'm pretty newbie to javacc. So please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    parser.start() ;
    System.out.println("File parsed successfully.") ;
} catch( ParseException ex ) {
    // Syntax error
    System.out.println( ex.getMessage() ) ; }
} catch( TokenManagerError ex ) {
    // Lexical error
    System.out.println( ex.getMessage() ) ; }
} catch( Throwable ex ) {
    // Some other error
    System.out.println( ex.getMessage() ) ; }
```